# Installation of SQL Server 2008 on windows 7 64 bit

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am really confused. I want to download SQL Server 2008. I have windows 7, 64 bit.

First I have downloaded only Management Studio (`SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe`, 176.5 MB). I have installed that. But there was no instance.

Later I realised to download SQL Server Express (`SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe` 82.5 MB).

I have visited this page (http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=26729)

Now I came to know that Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Service Pack 1. If I need both tool and instance, I have to download `SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe` (329.9 MB).

Will it work for Windows 7? Has anybody installed this? What is about Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express?

What I have to download Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP1 or Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It depends on **what you want** - do you want SQL Server **2008**? Or do you want **2008 R2** ?? (or to confuse you even more: do you want SQL Server **2012**). **Express** is the free edition for each of those SQL Server **versions** - and of course, to actually have the server instance, you have to download the **server** (not just the management studio tools). Service Packs are bug fixes and smaller enhancements, available for all versions and editions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you really want is `SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 with Advanced Services`, which includes SQL Server Management Studio SSMS;

http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30438

Choose `SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe`

This works just fine on Win 7 64 Bit (Which is what I'm running while typing this)

Comment: Thanks PGallagher for ur help.

Comment: No problems... Glad I could help!